# My Lumia 520 keeps rebooting continuously and won't start properly

Tags: lumia-520

After I tried to update my Lumia 520 to Windows Phone 10 insider preview, I got the gear screen without any progress in the update... so I tried removing the SIM and the SD memory and restarting the phone pressing the Volume down and power button at the same time... After this the phone kept on a loop showing the telecom company and the nokia logo, then restarting and doing the same thing over and over. I tried doing a hard reset but it doesn't answers. I tried using the windows device recovery tool but when I connect the phone to the PC the program will not detect the phone because it keeps rebooting... What can I do?